# re-direct stdout continuously in python from a function

Tags: python, redirect, subprocess, stdout

I have rather unusual use case of stdout.
Imagine I have a code below, where it performs some intense calculations.

```
def const_print():
    count = 0
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(f"Waited for {count} seconds\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        count+=1
        time.sleep(1)

        if count > 5:
            sys.stdout.write(f"Waited long enough. Exiting...\n")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            break

    return 'result of intense calculation'
```

While the function is being executed, I'd like to capture the stdout from this function and pipe it to another place (AMPQ message backend).

I can do something like this to capture it, but the problem is that instead of opening a subprocess, I'd like to open the function 'natively' so that i can get python object as a return of the const_print() function.

I am not allowed to modify the function itself (it is a lot more complicated function than what I showed, but the behavior is similiar, it constantly outputs some status in a form of stdout).

```
p = Popen("python const_print.py",
    shell=False,
    stdout=PIPE,
)

while p.poll() is None:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line)
        channel.basic_publish(amqp.Message(line), routing_key="QUEUE")
```

Any suggestion other than WHY DO I NEED TO DO THIS is very welcomed... Thank you...!

Comment: You can reassign `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to `StringIO` objects or whatever is convenient for your use case. You probably want to remember the original values so that you can restore them later.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, although, you can also use the [the standard lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

Comment: The examples I googled and what @juanpa.arrivillaga has added seems like it is 'static' and not really piping in real time? I am trying to get this piped in real time, perhaps like in threaded situation?

Comment: @user3655233  it is not "static", although, I don't really know what you mean. Can you be more specific? In any case, if you need to involve threads, well then you can involve threads.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry about that. It posted before I was able to add more details. Basically this function will be running for awhile and I need to pipe it to another place while it is running. Does that help a bit more? Looks like the string buffers is being used to dump stdout into it, but how do i get it 'out' of the buffer in real time?